# Changed computer now can not compile

Tags: c, compiler-errors, mpfr

I have encountered a problem which I do not know where to begin with.  I developed code on my laptop and it works fine.  I moved to another computer and now during compilation I get,

> error: unknown type name 'mpfr_exp_t'

The mpfr library is located in the same place on both computers.  Can anyone give me a clue how to learn what is wrong on the new computer?

Comment: How exactly do you expect to get help without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to give a verifiable example because my code works on one computer.  I would like help how to follow this type of problem through the compilation, for example some compiler flags that give more information.  Maybe such help is not possible.

Comment: http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Installing-MPFR states "The official type for exponent values changed from `mp_exp_t` to `mpfr_exp_t` in MPFR 3.0", maybe you don't have the lib installed or need the 3.0 version

Comment: @downshift you have out googled me, thanks a lot.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you included the right header files and compiled with `-Wall` `-Wextra` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MPFR libraries changed some syntax between versions.  In particular, as stated in the comments,

"The official type for exponent values changed from mp_exp_t to mpfr_exp_t in MPFR 3.0".

Changing the code fixes the problem.